# In train and test split, how to use the whole dataset for training?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataset of 212 observation and 4 columns. Now I want to use this whole dataset for training, how to do this?

I tried this-

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

Data_Train,Data_Test,Target_Train,Target_Test = train_test_split(DATA,TARGET,train_size=212,random_state=999)
```

but the error is popping saying ->  *train_size=212 should be either positive and smaller than the number of samples 212 or a float in the (0, 1) range*

Comment: If you don't want to split at all, why are you using `train_test_split` in the first place?

Comment: is there any other way to use it for training only?

Comment: Yes... just use your data for training without splitting it.

Answer (score 3):

Just as timgeb pointed out, once your test is done and you want to predict unseen values based on a model that is trained on the whole dataset, you simply don't call `train_test_split` at all.

Supposing you are fitting a simple linear regression model, what you need is probably something like this

```
from sklearn import linear_model
reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
reg.fit(DATA, TARGET)
score = reg.predict(NO_TARGET_DATA)
```

Where `NO_TARGET_DATA` represents your actual test set (what you called a test set in your snippet is actually more of a validation set, since you have targets for it and you use it to calculate your performance metrics).